# Retrofit 2 - how to avoid duplicate posts

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 to upload pictures, and I am getting too many duplicated pictures because users click upload button more than once.

disabling the button not a solution for my case, because the user can close the activity and reopen it again.

How to know if there is a running request or not before start proceeding upload request.
and the second question is how to get the progress of running upload after recreating the activity?

```
 VisitService visitService = ServiceGenerator.createService(VisitService.class,token);

        retrofit2.Call<UploadResult> req = visitService.PostImage(vId,picType,body2);

        req.enqueue(new Callback<UploadResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadResult> call, Response<UploadResult> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        uploadResult = response.body();

                  //..
```

Comment: you can try to disable "retry" on fail using this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33156592/737925

Comment: You can only call, `response.body()` once, by the way

Comment: @MoshErsan .. will disabling retry prevent user from creating new call request for the same picture?

Comment: @JaffarShehab you have to run the upload class in a background service and have an array of already uploaded images paths, then when user tries to upload the image again you check the array if it was already processed or uploaded you avoid the call.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?